# How to set QMDIArea background as transparent in QT?

Tags: qt

I have QMDIArea and inside it I have added a QMDISubWindow. I need QMDIArea to be completely transparent. By default it is displayed in grey color.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QMdiArea area = new QMdiArea();
    area->setStyleSheet("background:transparent;");
    area->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    this->setCentralWidget(area);

    MyChildScreenDialog *dlg = new MyChildScreenDialog ();
    area->addSubWindow(dlg );
}
```

But unfortunatlly, setting background:transaprent and setting attribute Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground won't work in QMdiArea.

Can we make QMdiArea as transparent? What modification we need to do in above code?

Answer (score 1):

I could able to resolve this by below code.

```
area->setBackground(QBrush(Qt::transparent));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using only QSS, this is the way to go:

```css
QMdiArea {
    qproperty-background: transparent;
}
```